# finding similar sequences (row-wise) in pandas and NDFrame

Tags: python, pandas, row

I am still learning python but I am becoming more and more fluent with dataframes.
I am trying to measure inside a pandas data frame which are the most frequent rows for different lengths. 
For example for a table of 5 columns: 
-Find the most appearing 3 elements out of the 5 columns that are the most frequent ones and so on.

then after working on this myself, I was able to find out that the groupby and aggregate. Below is some code I wrote, that you can also execute

```py
smallData=pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,3,3],[1,2,2,3,3],[1,2,3,5,3],[1,2,3,5,3]]),columns=['1', '2','3','4','5'])
keep=smallData.groupby(['1', '2','3','4','5']).size()
```

This returned me this nice table that shows at the same time how similar the different rows are:

```py
keep
Out[414]: 
1  2  3  4  5
1  2  2  3  3    1
      3  3  3    1
         4  5    1
         5  3    2
4  5  6  7  8    1
dtype: int64
```

The last column now is the frequency of each series. My real data set is much bigger and I would like to pick the last column and sort it so to find out which are the most common occurring sequences.

The keep variable though does not seem to be anymore a data frame but something I see for first time.

```py
keep.describe
Out[413]: 
<bound method NDFrame.describe of 1  2  3  4  5
1  2  2  3  3    1
      3  3  3    1
         4  5    1
         5  3    2
4  5  6  7  8    1
dtype: int64>
```

Also the shape of this structure seem to not be a matrix like type of structure

```py
keep.shape
Out[412]: (5,)
```

Can you please help me here accessing the values or finding the most frequent similar sequences in some other way?

I would like to thank you in advance for your help.
Regards
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

> DataFrame.**mode**(axis=0, numeric_only=False, dropna=True)[source]
>
> Get the mode(s) of each element along the selected axis.
>
> The mode of a set of values is the value that appears most often. It
>   can be multiple values.
>
> **axis** : *{0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0*
>
> The axis to iterate over while searching for the mode:
>
> - 0 or ‘index’ : get mode of each column
> - 1 or ‘columns’ : get mode of each row
>
> **numeric_only** : *bool, default False*
>
> If True, only apply to numeric columns.
>
> **dropna** : *bool, default True*
>
> Don’t consider counts of NaN/NaT.

[Source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html)